# How to split the Sentence and show in new lines in C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Objective is to split string and show line breaks in the format. 

I have tried using `Environment.NewLine` but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
stringArray = kidsCampDto.Message.Split(",".ToCharArray());

if (stringArray[0].Equals("successful."))
{
    lblSuccessMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lblSuccessMessage.Text = string.Format("Registration & Payment Information:-" +Environment.NewLine
        + "Welcome to kids camp Programs, Successful Registered with Kids camp." + Environment.NewLine
        + "Athlet+e ID: {0} {1}." + Environment.NewLine
        + "Amount paid: ${2}." + Environment.NewLine
        + "Paid By: {3}." + Environment.NewLine
        + "Transaction Id: {4}." + Environment.NewLine
        + "Transaction Date:{5}." + Environment.NewLine
        + "Program: {6}",
        kidsCampDto.AthleteFirstName,
        kidsCampDto.AthleteLastName, stringArray[3], 
        kidsCampDto.CreditCardSelected == true ? "Credit card" : "Bank Account", stringArray[1],
        Convert.ToDateTime(stringArray[2]).ToShortDateString(),
        kidsCampDto.SeasonTrainingProgram.Equals("0") ? "4 weeks" : (kidsCampDto.SeasonTrainingProgram.Equals("1") ? "8 weeks" : "12 weeks"));
}
```

Comment: Not related to the answer, but you can pass `Environment.Newline` as a parameter into a format specification location `{1}` and re-use that number multiple times throughout the string. That would eliminate the multiline `+` string joining in your above `string.Format` call.

Answer (score 3):

Replace **Environment.NewLine** with **`<br />`** tag.